# Parallelizing NDSolve and Parareal method

Tags: differential-equations, parallelization

I found this video on Youtube outlining a method for Parallelizing NDSolve  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TiO3nRWZ_U.

Does anyone know what the current update is on this? I tried to implement in Mathematica 11 with the example in the video

```
eqs = {{y1'[t] == y2[t], y2'[t] == -Sin[y1[t]]}, {y1[0] == 1/2, 
  y2[0] == 0}};
vars = {y1[t], y2[t]};
tf = 1000;
time = {t, tf, tf}; 
prsol1 = First[
NDSolve[eqs, vars, time, 
 Method -> {"Parareal", "SerialMethod" -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", 
   "ParallelMethod" -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

but it comes back with the message that

```
NDSolve::bdmtd: The value of the option Method     
->{Parareal,SerialMethod->ExplicitRungeKutta,ParallelMethod->ExplicitRungeKutta} 
is not a known built-in method, a symbol that could be a user-defined method,
 or a list with a name followed by method options.
```

Thanks!

Comment: I do believe this isn't in the kernel yet and a developmental build was being used in the video.

Answer (score 4):

The example now runs without error (V12.2 or earlier), but it gives different (and incorrect) results than the unparallelized call.  I guess it is still a work in progress.

```
eqs = {{y1'[t] == y2[t], y2'[t] == -Sin[y1[t]]},
       {y1[0] == 1/2, y2[0] == 0}};
vars = {y1, y2};
tf = 100;
time = {t, 0, tf};
prsol1 = First[
    NDSolve[eqs, vars, time, 
     Method -> {"Parareal", "SerialMethod" -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", 
       "ParallelMethod" -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
prsol2 = First[
    NDSolve[eqs, vars, time,
     Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.062579, Null}
  {0.002873, Null}
*)
```

Visualize the solutions:

```
Plot[{y1[t], y2[t]} /. prsol1 // Evaluate, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{y1[t], y2[t]} /. prsol2 // Evaluate, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

The parallel version does not satisfy the ODEs:

```
Plot[{y1'[t], y2[t]} /. prsol1 // Evaluate, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

But the unparallelized method does satisfy the ODEs:

```
Plot[{y1'[t], y2[t]} /. prsol2 // Evaluate, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]